# How to use Visual Studio installed on Windows 10 from a virtual machine on that same machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have Visual Studio installed in Windows 10, and also have a 32 bits Windows 7 virtual machine installed on that. I want to run my code on that 32 bits virtual machine.

From the Windows 7 VM, can I run (share) Visual Studio that is installed on the Windows 10 host, without actually installing it on that VM?

Comment: Are you looking for a portable version, that doesn't have to be installed (e.g. in a Zip-file)?

Comment: Yes ! I want to share Visual studio of windows 10 to Vm Windows 7..But i didn't found any appropriate way to do this ..

Comment: Please check if my edits describe your question well?

Comment: Yes! it is. Thank-You!